# use java script to ensure a the textboxes are not empty

Tags: javascript

I have created a form in which we have text boxes for names, ages and birth date. As part of the project i am supposed to use java script. So i need a java script function that will check whether the text boxes are empty and shows an alert message when the submit button is clicked. I am new to java script.Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Try that way

```
var textarea = document.querySelector('textarea'); // your textarea selector

if(textarea.value == '') {
    // show errors
} else {
    // submit
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is an example of how this could be done, using jQuery.

```js
window.onload = function (){

  $("#submit").click( function() {
    var empty = 0;
    $(".input").each( function() {
      if( $(this).val() == ""){
        $("#error").html("Error! Some fields are empty");
        empty = 1;
      }
    });
    
    if(empty == 0)
      $("#error").html("OK!");
  });

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="error"></div>
Name: <input class="input" type="text" ><br>
Age: <input class="input" type="text" ><br>
DOB: <input class="input" type="text" ><br><br>
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="Send">
```

Comment: thanx bro..let me try this one..and will let u know if i am getting an error or if i have any doubts..